# Button position on different browsers CSS

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have problem with CSS, can someone help me with it? I can make my design for one browser but then it breaks in another browser.

For example if I fix it for Chrome then it does not work for Firefox, and vice versa...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Bookmark Storage</title>
<style>
.frmsub{


}

.btnsub{
position:relative;
left:-80px;
bottom:-24px;

}
.btnclear{
position:relative;
right:-30px;
top:0px;

}
.mltsub{
position:relative;
right:-30px;
top:375px;
}
.load{
position:relative;
right:290px;
top:30px;

}
</style>

</head>
<body background="http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1F/l0/2CSIzyy1/notebook1.jpg">
<div align="center">
<div align="center">
<form class="frmsub" action="./BK.pl" method="POST">
URL: <input name="HWID" type="text">  <br>
Short description(optional): <input name="HWID1" type="text1">  <br>
<input class="btnsub" value="Submit" type="submit"></form>
<form  action="./clear.pl" method="POST">
<input class="btnclear" value="Clear" type="submit">
</form></div></div>
<div align="center"><form method="POST" action="./multiBK.pl">

<input class="mltsub" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form><form method="POST" action="./AddS.pl">
<textarea name="HWID" rows="20" cols="50">Add bookmark source here, press load and then submit.
</textarea>
<input class="load" value="Load" type="submit">
</form></div>


<p align="center"></p>
<div align="center">
<div align="center">&nbsp;</div></div>
<p align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Check your bookmarks: <a HREF="./newbm.html">Click</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Just look is important not pay attention to form...

Comment: Why are you using `position:fixed;` ?

Comment: I used position:relative; ...

Comment: Maybe you should make classes for those divs to set the standards for how the buttons should be placed within them.

Comment: Oops, I meant to ask why you were using `relative`, brain and hands didn't agree there -_-

Comment: Could you try fix my code I not good with design... Thanks in advance

Comment: `align=center` was deprecated many years ago and may be fighting whatever CSS you're using. Don't use it.

Comment: Have you looked into using a css reset? http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like Markus said, use a CSS Reset like this well know: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

if after applying it still not working well, maybe there's something wrong in your code

Comment: I posted the link, you've to copy his css in your stylesheet at a very beginning

Comment: put it in http://jsfiddle.net/ or post screenshots so we can undertstand WHAT is different from one browser to another

Comment: You can open it here: http://s-projects.site44.com/fix.html try in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try addin this to the top of your css file:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: How about a [CSSReset](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)? It's common practice. The cool kids do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try addin this to the top of your css file:

```
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

That way you can test if there is some default browser padding/margin issue without using some large css reset thingy...

What i can tell you is that i think the problem is that you are wrapping that in

which have default 10px bottom and top padding so maybe try reseting that to 0 in your css.

```
lineInput{
padding:0;
}
```

Or just change that paragraph to div.

Maybe that is the solution, but maybe it aint, because you are using absolut positioning...

I have counted the px's and letters in both part of the picture are 15px. In firefox below the letters to the end of the orange part is 11px and in chrom there is 8px. In firefox from top of the letters to the start of the orange part there is 12px and in chrom there is 10px. So that is 5px of difference.

Try this:

```
btnSubmit{
height:38px;
padding:0;
}
```

That will make the button be 38px high and letters will be in top left of the button. Then you could add maybe this:

```
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
```

// or how much is needed to be verticaly centered.